# glossaries package is printing all entries under acronyms

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to insert a glossary into a latex document using the `glossaries` package.  I would like to separate out the list of acronyms from the list of definitions.  My understanding is that this is normally achieved with two calls: i) one to `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` for the acronyms and ii) one to `\printglossary` for the definitions.

The issue I am running into is that the two aforementioned variations on calls to `\printglossary` both seem to produce the same thing -- a list of all acronyms and all definitions combined.  I illustrate below a minimum working example of the problem, in code and in output.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,xindy,acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries 

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{Ay Bee See}
\newacronym{def}{DEF}{Dee Eee Eff}
\newacronym{ghi}{GHI}{Gee Hach Eye}

\newglossaryentry{onetwothree} 
{ 
name={One Two Three}, 
description={The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}
}

\begin{document}
Here is some text

\gls{abc}, \gls{def}, \gls{ghi}, \gls{onetwothree}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Note I made a call to `makeglossaries <filename_without_extension>` on the terminal before compiling the example code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nomain` package option suppresses the creation of the main (default) glossary. This means that there's only one glossary (the `acronym` glossary) which becomes the new default glossary, so `\glsdefaulttype` and `\acronymtype` expand to the same glossary label. Since `\printglossary` is equivalent to `\printglossary[type=\glsdefaulttype]` this means that `\printglossary` and `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` are displaying the same glossary (the `acronym` glossary).

Since you want two separate glossaries, remove the `nomain` package option.