# Problems printing Acronyms

Tags: acronyms

I'm having problems printing a page with acronyms.
I have tried the examples/solutions provided in
[How to print all the acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367086/how-to-print-all-the-acronyms)
or
[glossaries package is printing all entries under acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205256/glossaries-package-is-printing-all-entries-under-acronyms)
with no additional code but with no success.
A page is created but blank.
Do I need to install something? I have read about xindy, pearl...?
Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
  \newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
  \newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
  \newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
\begin{document}
  \glsaddall
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]
\end{document}
```

Comment: depending on the packages you're using, either run `makeindex`, `xindy` or any other index creating tool. for further information, please provide a MWE.

Comment: Try [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries).